# Blackbody radiation graph confusion

Tags: quantum-mechanics, thermal-radiation

If [Wien's law](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wien%27s_displacement_law) showed what was expected when a blackbody was heated but the familiar peaked curves is actually what happened, how were those peaked curves produced?

[image]

I am assuming an experiment wasn't really carried out as those temperatures $(4000~\mathrm K+)$ would be difficult or impossible to produce at the end of the 19th century. I don't see how those graphs could have been produced (therefore highlighting the problem) before Planck suggested quantisation. There must be a problem in my understanding but I don't know where.

Comment: People were melting iron and glass and firing ceramics at the end of the nineteenth century, which requires 1000 K to 2000 K temperatures. They were also producing incandescent light bulbs. I don't think there is any reason why people could not have reached 4000 K temperatures at that time.

Comment: In fact the German government set up a dedicated company/university to concentrate on this specific problem at the end of the 1800's

Comment: Thank you for the various edits. This is my first post. So some scientists actually would have heated some material to these temperatures and recorded the EM radiation emitted?

Answer (score 1):

Here is described the history of [black body radiation studies](http://galileo.phys.virginia.edu/classes/252/black_body_radiation.html):

> What Was Observed: the Complete Picture
>
> By the 1890’s, experimental techniques had improved sufficiently that it was possible to make fairly precise measurements of the energy distribution in this cavity radiation, or as we shall call it black body radiation.  In 1895, at the University of Berlin, Wien and Lummer punched a small hole in the side of an otherwise completely closed oven, and began to measure the radiation coming out.
>
> The beam coming out of the hole was passed through a diffraction grating, which sent the different wavelengths/frequencies in different directions, all towards a screen.  A detector was moved up and down along the screen to find how much radiant energy was being emitted in each frequency range. (This is a theorist’s model of the experiment—actual experimental arrangements were much more sophisticated.  For example, to make the difficult infrared measurements higher frequency waves were eliminated by multiple reflections from quartz and other crystals.)  They found a radiation intensity/frequency curve close to this (correct one):

[image: wien black body]

> The visible spectrum begins at around 4.3×10^14 Hz, so this oven glows deep red.
>
> One minor point: *this plot is the energy density inside the oven,*

Please look at the link for more information.

Comment: That's an excellent article. Thank you. So high temperatures were indeed possible for scientists in the 1890s.